# Question concerning Feynman lectures volume 3 chapter 7-2

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am currently reading The Feynman lectures on physics volume 3. In chapter 7-2 (7.9) Feynman said the amplitudes of a moving particle are given by the equation $e^{-(i/\hbar)(W_pt-p\cdot x)}$. Where $W_p$ is the energy of the particle over and above its rest energy, and $p$ is the particle's momentum, and $x$ is its displacement, and $t$ is time.

Since Feynman goes on to derive the de Broglie wavelength equation ($\lambda=h/p$) from this expression I would really like to understand where it comes from.

Link to chapter 7-2: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_07.html#Ch7-S2

Comment: You were missing a minus sign in the exponent of the wave function. I have added the minus sign and now it matches with the expression $(7.9)$ of Feynman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feynman is considering a particle with a definite momentum $p$.

- From solving the eigenvalue problem for the momentum operator $\hat{p}=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, we know that the wavefunction of a momentum eigenstate with a given momentum $p$ is given by $e^{ipx}$ up to normalization.
- We also know that an energy-eigenstate $\psi_E$ with an energy $E$ evolves in time as $e^{-iEt}\psi_E$ according to the Schrodinger equation.

Now, if you consider a free particle, a momentum eigenstate is also an energy eigenstate (because the momentum operator and the Hamiltonian commute) and thus, a particle with a momentum $p$ would have the wavefunction given by $e^{-iE_{p}t}e^{ipx} = e^{-i(Et-px)}$ at time $t$ where $E_p$ is just the energy of the particle with momentum $p$. This is exactly what $(7.9)$ says.

So, it simply comes from applying the Schrodinger equation to a particle who is in a momentum eigenstate and is free.